# How to remove text before and after in a word

Tags: linux, text-processing, hp-ux

I have the line below:

```
create table "sacro".issue
```

The desired outcome I want is below:

```
"sacro"
```

I want to remove everything before the first double quote and everything after the last double quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo 'create table "sacro".issue' | cut -d '"' -f 2
sacro
```

This treats the string `create table "sacro".issue` as a `"`-delimited list and cuts out the second field, which is the word in quotes.

If you want the quotes:

```
$ echo 'create table "sacro".issue' | cut -d '"' -f 2 | sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/'
"sacro"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the shell, using the POSIX prefix/suffix-eating expansions:

```
$ s='create table "sacro".issue'
$ t="${s#*\"}"                       # remove up to first "
$ t="${t%\"*}"                       # remove after last "
$ echo "\"$t\""                      # put the quotes back...
"sacro"
```

If you're grepping for the data from a file, it's easier to think if this the other way around, to only keep the quoted part. Assuming your `grep` has `-o`, that is:

```
$ echo 'create table "sacro".issue' > file
$ grep -o '".*"' file
"sacro"
```